# Does Path.Combine ever make network calls in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, uri, filepath

Someone I know is claiming that it does and I am decompiling System.IO and looking in the Path class and I can't see it making networking calls. The only suspect is in NormalizePath, where it calls to PathHelper which has calls into Win32Native.GetFullPathName. I don't know what that does.

They are also claiming that System.Uri makes networking calls when created, which I find very incredible. I just can't believe that it would do that given how unbelievably slow that would be and how intrinsic these methods are.

Can anyone enlighten me?

**Edit:**
It turns out that `Path.Combine(p)` doesn't ever call the network but `Path.GetFullName(p)` can. In the scenario where you have a UNC path with a short filename (`"\\server\abcdef~1.txt"` for example) it will actually call out to the network and try to expand the path, which blows my mind frankly.

Comment: My thought, that maybe he meant some cases where you use those things in some context, when of course some network calls could be made. For example, you could feed WPF's BitmapImage with URI, which would make network call to download image from network, if uri would target network resource of course, which doesn't mean, that just making an uri would make any calls by itself

Comment: Thanks Ravadre, I will have to clarify that because that does seem most likely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the `Path.Combine` method simply performs the required string manipulation to generate a legal path string, given the path separator. It explicitly does **not** check to see if you've given it a valid path, or a valid file name, or whatever.

The reference source code for .NET 4 is available, if you're curious, and you can see that the work is done entirely in managed code, no native method calls, and is basically:

```
return path1 + (path1.EndsWidth("\") ? "" : "\") + path2;
```

(A lot more robust and flexible, of course, but that's the idea.)

Similarly, the constructors for the Uri class do mostly string parsing (though orders of magnitude more complex than the Path stuff) but still, no network calls that I can see.

You could also check this yourself by running a packet capture utility such as Wireshark while executing such commands in a C# app.

Comment: What about GetDirectoryName()? Or GetFullPath()? I'm convinced you're right about Path.Combine.

Comment: Obviously I don't have the source for those :) But the MSDN pages explicitly state that neither function checks to see if it's returning a *valid* path, only that it's a *legal* path, which means they have no reason to hit the network.

Comment: It actually will make a network call in GetFullPath() if you have a UNC path with a windows short name such as "\\server\files\testme~1.txt", calling GetFullPath(p) will return the actual full name of the file... but other than that it appears to not ever make network calls.